# What does this mean? 行動に理由ができる

Tags: translation, meaning, particles

> 行動に理由ができる。

Is it like: " I will find my reasons in my actions" ?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: What's the context?

Answer (score 2):

Without any context, it literally just means "A reason is made for acting".

Depending on the context, yes, it can mean "I find a reason for doing so" or something like this.